# How to Get All Channels Inputs of an ADC at a Time

Tags: arduino-uno, adc, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm using an 8 channel **ADS-1256** for Raspberry Pi Zero and want to read analog inputs of all the channels at a time without much delay. Is it possible?
If not possible then Please clearly state how would ADC work and how to store data of all channels.

I connected SDA and SCL pins and was willing to read data from all channels pins but it does not give correct readings.